# In which sequence or manner multiple functions is called if i call them inside ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have this code.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="func1(); func2(); func3()">Click</button>
```

I want to know that how func1,func2, and func3 will be called? Is it according to their sequence or parallelly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple, it will call in sequence.

First func1() will be called and then func2() and then func3().

Answer (score 1):

It's sequentially, you can simply test it:

```js
angular.module("app", [])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.func1 = function() {
    console.log('1');
  }
  $scope.func2 = function() {
    console.log('2');
  }
  $scope.func3 = function() {
    console.log('3');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <button type="button" ng-click="func1(); func2(); func3()">Click</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks developer033

Answer (score 1):

According to sequence

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<button type="button" ng-click="func1(); func2(); func3()">Click</button>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.func1= function(){
alert("1");
};
    $scope.func2= function(){
alert("2");
};
    $scope.func3= function(){
alert("3");
};
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vKWRwr

Comment: Thanks @Naga Sai A

Comment: Yes Naga Sai A.. it helps me and that's why i have to